# Load partial xml using xerces dom parser

Tags: c++, dom, xerces, xerces-c

The xml file that i get is huge in size, however while i need only specific parts of the file in random manner (hence cannot use SAX) while processing.
Is there any way by which i can load only a partial dom tree in memory using xerces dom parser?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you want is something like [Python's pulldom](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.dom.pulldom.html) which Xerces does not offer.

If you are beholden to Xerces and memory is a primary concern, you could use Xerces SAX (push) parser to populate a data structure with only the data from the XML that you care about.  Then you could "randomly" access the data that you are interested in.

If you are free to use other libraries, you might look into a [StAX (pull) parser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/StAX).  Although, I think you will still have to implement your own data structure to hold the data you're interested in.  I'm not aware of a C++ equivalent of Python's pulldom.